# Load Entry Via Ajax - After filtering from dropdown menu

Tags: ee2, channel, entries, ajax, filter

I am wondering if you can point me in the right direction here. Here is what I want to happen.

1) Site visitor visits the site and sees an elected official displayed on the home page. Next to this elected official is a dropdown list with a listing of all the counties for their state. 
2) The user can select another county from this list and then hit a submit button. 
3) That portion of the web page refreshes (filters) and the picture and content of the elected official is displayed to match the county (entry) for that official per the users selection.

Because this is housed on the home page, I would like for it (the entry) to load via ajax. So when a visitor chooses a new county and hits the submit button, you see the new entry displayed without reloading.

The county for the official is saved as a custom field text box within their entry.

Any recommendations on how to do this? Does this make sense?

Comment: This isn't an EE specific question... Better asked on http://stackoverflow.com IMO

Answer (score 0):

Just curious.  Something like this?   This page is still under development but I think it's sort of what you're looking for.  If it is, I'll explain in detail.  http://sitstringsdesign.com/products/pedal-steel-lap-steel/sc8e7th